# How to fix the unresolved dependencies for Anorm in scala version 2.13

Tags: scala, anorm, scala-2.13

I would like to import anorm dependencies on to my scala play frame work project but it doesn't support on my current scala version. What should I do?

```scala
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.3.9"
```

Error shown:

> sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#anorm_2.13;2.3.9: not found

Comment: It means that version of anorm doesn't exist, at least where you're looking for it.

Comment: ... or that version doesn't exist for your current version of Play. What Play version are you using? [The docs suggest](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaAnorm#Add-Anorm-to-your-project) that a recommended version is `2.5.1` - is there a reason why you're using such a low version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version that you use for anorm is too old 2.3.9 . The artifact of this library is already moved to "org.playframework.anorm".

You already using scala 2.13 so you have to use :

```
"org.playframework.anorm" %% "anorm" % "2.6.4"
```